# os.listdir changing returned file name on FAT16 USB flash drive

Tags: python, macos, fat16

I have the following segment of code:

```
os.listdir('./')
```

This returns something like

```
...
'ena-drift-try1-2013-10-02-064315.odf',
'ena-drift-try1-2013-10-02-065315.odf',
'ENA-DR~6.ODF',
'ena-drift-try1-2013-10-02-071315.odf',
'ena-drift-try1-2013-10-02-072315.odf',
...
```

The name of the middle file is actually

```
ena-drift-try1-2013-10-02-070315.odf
```

I am running OS X 10.6.8 on a 32-bit machine, Enthought Python 7.3-2, Python 2.7.3, and iIython 0.13.1. The files are data files that were generated on a Windows XP machine using Python and are located on a USB flash drive formatted in FAT16. I have changed the location on the flash drive in order to shorten the overall path and the error still remains.

When the files are copied to the hard drive, the code has no problem and the file name is not altered.

The same code can be run with no problems on RHEL 6.3, IPython 0.12, and Python 2.7.2 when the files are copied onto the server's hard drive.

Why is listdir altering the name of this one file when it is stored on a FAT16 flash drive?

Comment: Weird .. I feel sure it would be something else in the OS doing this, and not python

Comment: If you do `ls` at the command line does it show the correct or incorrect name?

Comment: That's the munged 8.3 file name... fat16 on osx is pretty spotty (shadow files and etc...) and there may be some stale value in there. Try deleting all files (including hidden). Or better, move to NTFS [Format a USB Drive as NTFS in Windows XP](http://lifehacker.com/5195783/format-a-usb-drive-as-ntfs-in-windows-xp)

Comment: The `ls` command does produce the correct name.